# Custom horizontal progressbar

Tags: android

Hey,
I just wrote a horizontal progress bar. The progressbar gets this background resource:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bg" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:gravity="center">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

This works fine, but the white progress has the same height as the background. But I want the progress to be smaller than the background of the progress bar, since thre background has a boarder that should not overlap.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

You can try adding `android:top`, `android:left`,`android:right`, and `android:bottom` to the white progress bar `item` in order to add padding to the bar.

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:gravity="center"
    android:top="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Comment: Hi, this does nit change it, the white progress is still as big as the whole background image...

Answer (score 2):

There is also :

```
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"></item>
```

Did you changed it too?

Answer (score 1):

Hi actually I did not use it.

The full xml is:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bg" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:gravity="center">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

hi try adding stroke that has no color (opacity is max)
I tried this code with my gradient progress bar:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dip" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#f8d79b"
                android:centerY="0.5"
                android:endColor="#f8d79b"
                android:startColor="#f8d79b" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <stroke
                    android:width="5px"
                    android:color="#00ffffff" />
                <corners android:radius="10dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:angle="0"
                    android:endColor="#ffac17"
                    android:startColor="#ffac17" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

so your code should be like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bg" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:gravity="center">
    <clip>
        <shape>
           <stroke
                    android:width="5px"
                    android:color="#00ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

worked for me, hope it works for you :D